# How to solve this constrained nonlinear system of equations for positive values?

Tags: matlab, optimization

How can I solve this system for positive values of x?
I used fval but it can't find the answer and asks for larger iterations which is unhelpful...
  **a must be positive and smaller than 0.05

b must be larger than 88**

```
function F = Final_Project_2(x)
 F = [(1/x(1)) + (1/x(2))- (2/(7*x(3)));
       (x(3)+2*x(4))*(15*x(2))/((x(1)+x(2))*x(3)-0.7/x(3))-14;
       (x(3)*((0.576*x(2)/(x(1)+x(2))*x(3)) - 0.27/x(3)))/(x(3)+(0.576*x(2)/(x(1)+x(2))*x(3)) - 0.27/x(3)) - a;
       ((0.576*x(2)*x(3)/(x(1)+x(2))*x(3)) - 0.27*x(4)/x(3))-b];
```

**Edit:**
How this question is "too localized"?!!
I derived this system of equations from designing a Common Emitter Amplifier. First equation is came from independency from $/betha /$. Second one is kvl from Collector to Emitter. Third one is the CE gain.Last one is R_in

Comment: Completely unclear statement. What are you trying to solve for? The vector x, or a and b? Even with that, there is no presumption that a solution MUST exist.

Comment: Anyway, how is this question different from your first question, on exactly the same thing?

Comment: @woodchips not that unclear... Perhaps not well phrased but its a typical problem in optimization.  The poster's last question was a syntax question - this is a question on how to solve the system.  I disagree with the closing as this type of problem is hit by many engineers with real world design problems.

Comment: Is it unclear? I just want to solve for positive values of x. Also some constants in equations may be arbitrary chosen. I can't understand why should this question should be closed?!  My first question may look similar to this one but it is more complicated because of the constraints in it

Comment: @ccook - unclear because no place in the statement do we learn that x is to be solved for, or is it a and b? After all, it appears that constraints were placed on a and b.

Comment: @woodchips I still disagree, x usually implies the independent variable and the constraints on a and b imply they are to be solved as well.  Frankly, this is much less localized than the topics covered in other languages - just less familiar to web developers (who largely closed this).

Comment: @PooyaM Did my answer solve this for you?

Comment: @ccook - While I agree that x USUALLY implies a variable to be solved for, there was NO statement of this fact. Are the constraints on a and b simply there to tell us what to expect for a pair of constants? Or are they variables? Without clarification, this is simply a mess of a question, an unclear thought.

Comment: @woodchips Sure, but I think its more helpful to fix the question than discard it.  Or at least "Not a real question", not "too localized"

Comment: @ccook - to be honest, I'm not sure what I flagged it as, but I don't think I ticked off "too localized". But it is the majority who rule in that respect anyway. Regardless, this question still appears to be far too close to the previous question by the same person on the same topic. Asking the same question multiple times, slightly differently each time does not gain favor on this site.

Comment: @woodchips Sure, though - the last was a syntax question.  Anyway - clarity would definitely have helped.  I do think there was a good question there waiting to be asked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would fit well under the non linear constrained optimization category, fmincon is helpful here.  Fmincon allows you to solve the non linear system while placing upper and lower bounds on the solution vector.  The problem is that the solution will depend on your starting point... So if you have a good guess for where the solution *should* be that helps ***GREATLY***.

The analogy is like asking the solver to climb to the top of the mountain in front of it, or asking it to find the tallest peak in Europe by backpacking from some random starting point. When you are close you can just walk 'up'.

Anyway, here's how you can do this.

```
function test()

    a = .05
    b = 88


    xo = [100 100 100 100 a b]


    options = optimset('MaxFunEvals',1E5, ...
        'MaxIter', 1E5, ...
        'TolFun', 1E-32, ...
        'TolX', 1E-32, ...
        'TolCon', 1E-32);

    x = fmincon(@(X) Ftest(X), xo, [], [], [], [], ...
        [-inf -inf -inf -inf a b], [], [],  options)

    Final_Project_2(x)

    function F = Ftest(x)
        F = norm(Final_Project_2(x))
    end

    function F = Final_Project_2(x)
        F = [(1/x(1)) + (1/x(2))- (2/(7*x(3)));
               (x(3)+2*x(4))*(15*x(2))/((x(1)+x(2))*x(3)-0.7/x(3))-14;
               (x(3)*((0.576*x(2)/(x(1)+x(2))*x(3)) - 0.27/x(3)))/(x(3)+(0.576*x(2)/(x(1)+x(2))*x(3)) - 0.27/x(3)) - x(5);
               ((0.576*x(2)*x(3)/(x(1)+x(2))*x(3)) - 0.27*x(4)/x(3))-x(6)];
    end


end
```

> x =
>
> 258.0438   84.3372   24.9576   34.8035    3.0926   88.0000
>
> ans =
>
> ```
> 0.0043    -0.0000
> 0.0001    -0.0000
> ```

Note how the solver slammed against the lower bound on b.  You can try playing with the initial guess and see if you can get it to find a nicer min.  No solution is guaranteed...

***This is the fun part***, you can do better.  Your system is not just a cost function but *a constraint on x*.  Similar code, but using that information and you have a strong solution.

```
function test()

    a = .05
    b = 88


    xo = [100 100 100 100 a b]


    options = optimset('MaxFunEvals',1E4, ...
        'MaxIter', 1E4, ...
        'TolFun', 1E-32, ...
        'TolX', 1E-32, ...
        'TolCon', 1E-32);

    x = fmincon(@(X) Ftest(X), xo, [], [], [], [], ...
        [-inf -inf -inf -inf a b], [], @(X) xcon(X),  options)

    Final_Project_2(x)

    function F = Ftest(x)
        F = norm(Final_Project_2(x))
    end

    function [c,ceq] = xcon(x)
        c = []
        ceq = [(1/x(1)) + (1/x(2))- (2/(7*x(3)));
            (x(3)+2*x(4))*(15*x(2))/((x(1)+x(2))*x(3)-0.7/x(3))-14;
            (x(3)*((0.576*x(2)/(x(1)+x(2))*x(3)) - 0.27/x(3)))/(x(3)+(0.576*x(2)/(x(1)+x(2))*x(3)) - 0.27/x(3)) - x(5);
           ((0.576*x(2)*x(3)/(x(1)+x(2))*x(3)) - 0.27*x(4)/x(3))-x(6);
           (x(3)*((0.576*x(2)/(x(1)+x(2))*x(3)) - 0.27/x(3)))/(x(3)+(0.576*x(2)/(x(1)+x(2))*x(3)) - 0.27/x(3)) - x(5);
            ((0.576*x(2)*x(3)/(x(1)+x(2))*x(3)) - 0.27*x(4)/x(3))-x(6)];
    end

    function F = Final_Project_2(x)
        F = [(1/x(1)) + (1/x(2))- (2/(7*x(3)));
               (x(3)+2*x(4))*(15*x(2))/((x(1)+x(2))*x(3)-0.7/x(3))-14;
               (x(3)*((0.576*x(2)/(x(1)+x(2))*x(3)) - 0.27/x(3)))/(x(3)+(0.576*x(2)/(x(1)+x(2))*x(3)) - 0.27/x(3)) - x(5);
               ((0.576*x(2)*x(3)/(x(1)+x(2))*x(3)) - 0.27*x(4)/x(3))-x(6)];
    end


end
```

> x =
>
> 360.8859  132.2940   27.6590   34.2885    3.6943  117.8688
>
> ans =
>
> 1.0e-14 *
>
> -0.0002
>       0.1776    -0.0444
>            0

Think of the second method as giving the backpacker a set of trails/roads to use.  It guides the solver through the R^6 space.

Comment: You could also help the solver by moving some of the equations into the non linear constraints arguement.  It should help the solver.  For example, x(1) is constrained by x(2) and x(3).   A constraint is better than acost function.

Comment: I went ahead and added the suggestion to the solution.